# Removing a tag while improving a suggested edit triggers error, automatically rejects suggested edit

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

This might be a little convoluted, but bear with me:

1. I reviewed [a suggested edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/3720) which made some good changes but also added a meta tag (*dlc*) which shouldn't be there.
2. I clicked on the "Improve" button, removed the meta tag, filled in the description, made sure the "this edit was helpful" checkbox was checked, and clicked the "Save Edits" button.
3. I received an error stating the following:

   > Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
   >
   > - You seem to be improving a post however, you made no changes.
4. I made some additional minor changes just so the system would accept the improvement and clicked "Save Edits" again.
5. The [original suggestion was rejected](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/3720) by Community with no reason and [my edits were made](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/53904/revisions) as though I did all the work myself.

This doesn't seem kosher.

Comment: Did you do anything between step #3 and step #4?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd No: had I done anything, I surely would've included it like I did with all the other steps.

Comment: So the message was there but so was the edit form, intact with your existing tag changes in place? Sorry, just never got into such situation so thought maybe after the message you had to go back or reload.

Comment: There were other reports on site metas that suggested edits were declined even though the improving user had checked the "helpful" checkbox. Though those reports didn't have any specific suspicions under which conditions this happens.

Comment: This still is relevant.