# Edit Previous Revision -> Community Rejects Edit Pending Approval

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, revisions-list

## Extensive Backstory

Earlier, I stumbled on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455016/hittestobject-inaccuracies-vs-update-method). It had a [pending edit](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/256401), which fixed formatting errors in the code. I voted to approve the edit, and it still needed one more vote.

I looked at the tags, and noticed that the [update](/questions/tagged/update) tag was being used, a tag that had recently been listed for [burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012). I looked at the edit history, and saw that this tag had been added in an [edit by another user](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/10455016/2).

## Our Hero Discovers His Powers

I noticed for the first time that I had the option to edit previous revisions, so I thought I'd go ahead and pull that tag out. I went to edit the revision, removed the tag, and hit save.

## Surprise Plot Twist!

Imagine my surprise when, upon re-loading the question, the edit I had voted to approve had disappeared. With a little more research, I noticed that it had been [rejected by the Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/256401).

The edit I voted to approve is missing the tag that I attempted to remove, but the edit that I attempted to fix still was listed as adding the burninated tag and my edit had become a brand new revision. This appears to be a bug of some sort, but I'm not entirely sure what the correct behavior would be in this case.

Potential Options:

1. I should have been told I could not edit the revision I attempted to edit?
2. My edit should have changed the revision I attempted to edit and the edit I voted to approve?
3. My edit should have been interpreted as an improvement on the not-yet-approved edit?

## Epilogue

Related: [Similar Meta Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124970/removing-a-tag-while-improving-a-suggested-edit-triggers-error-automatically-re)
Related: [Similar Meta Question the 2nd](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131157/im-allowed-to-rollback-a-post-that-has-a-pending-suggested-edit)

Comment: Similar to [my reject question about the rollback link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131157/im-allowed-to-rollback-a-post-that-has-a-pending-suggested-edit), except mine doesn't get Community love.

Comment: Also, I recently learned about the edit link in the revision history. I'm not sure if it's by-design or not, but it's very useful for "improving" a suggested edit by setting it back to what it was before and editing from that. There really should be some sort of notice like "this will reject the pending suggested edit."

Comment: I'm tempted to tag this something like `[appropriate-MSO-humor]` so that I can cite it more easily the next time someone whines about getting downvotes/closevotes on a "Jon Skeet eating waffles while riding a unicorn" joke post.